# How to design workflow 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I want to design a workflow that users do not have access to deleted  item , but do delete item by workflow. To do what I do. that's mean  Users access denied delete item run workflow and workflow not canceled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce a soft delete option in your list/library. By ticking a Yes/No box or setting a choice field to Delete, this will trigger a workflow. In that workflow, you need to include an Impersonation Step. In this, you check to see if the field value indicates the user wants to delete the item, if it passes the check, the item is deleted.

The Impersonation step does just what it implies, it acts on behalf of someone else to do something they might not have access to do. In this case, it would be acting like you, the workflow author, to delete the file.

Comment: Workflow is run by one person and then another person if the request was not approved, they will be deleted from the list. What is Run as workflow owner? One person told me that an action set and enabled Run as workflow owner.